# Eulerian and hamiltonian graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently work on a problem about these two graphs I mentioned in the title:

[image]

- The maximum node degree is: $8$ because there are 8 nodes
- The graph has subgraphs: $8$ because of the 8 nodes(every node could be a subgraph)
- Is the graph an Eulerian graph: $YES$
- Is the graph an hamiltonian graph: $NO$
- Is this graph an acyclic graph: $NO$ because there are cycles in
  this graph
- Does the graph contains a spanning subtree:$YES$ because when you connect every outer border with a node you get a spanning subtree

Are my argumentations correct?

Comment: You will have to translate some of the German adjectives to English. For example, ‘eulerscher’ should be ‘Eulerian’ and ‘hamiltonischer’ should be ‘Hamiltonian’. Also, I would like to see the definition of an ‘exciting tree’. :)

Comment: I think one of the two "eulerscher" in the third and fourth bullets should be "hamiltonischer", or are you undecided? :) It might help to see how you got those numbers for the maximum node degree, the number of subgraphs, etc.

Comment: @HaskellCurry yes you are right, its hard if you only have a german textbook to translate it into proper english... btw I updated my post;)

Comment: The maximum node degree is 4 not 8!

Comment: @Jernej Why is the max node degree 4?

Comment: The degree of a node is the number of edges incident with the given node. Which vertex has the maximal number of incident edges to it and how many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are not entirely correct. Few corrections and comments following:

- Every graph (unless perhaps the empty graph) has subgraphs. Plenty of them. The graph on the picture has more than 8 subgraphs.
- The graph is clearly Hamiltonian (can you find a 8-cycle in it?)
- The graph indeed contains a spanning tree. In fact every **connected** graphs contains a spanning tree